# Why does pthread_create return an int?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have seen code for summation of an array using threads. In this code a thread is created and an `int` data type is returned:

```
int iret1, iret2;   
iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1); 
iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message2);
```

I knew that a thread is a child of a process and it uses for executing program. For the executing program memory is needed, and memory is returned by a `void*` data type.

What is the logical reason for returning an `int`? Can any one explain the actual reason?

Comment: This is the common pattern in POSIX API - take a handle on which to operate by pointer, and return an error code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `man pthread_create`:

> Return Value
>
> On success, pthread_create() returns 0; on error, it returns an error
>   number, and the contents of *thread are undefined.

That value simply indicates whether the thread creation was successful or not.

It is not a memory allocation call like `malloc`, therefore I don't see why you think it should return a pointer.

Comment: from what  resources it get memory?

Comment: Returning the `pthread_t` and setting `errno` for the error would have been more convenient for many uses, but the POSIX threads API was designed before it was established that `errno` would be required to be thread-local. Therefore, all of the pthread functions return error codes rather than setting errno (although of course they're also allowed to clobber errno).

Comment: @prjndhi: All child threads share the memory space of the process that creates them and have their own private stack. Hence, you can call `malloc` inside the thread function to allocate more heap memory like you would normally do.

Comment: @prjndhi: Yes, a thread can have child threads by calling `pthread_create` inside the thread function.

Comment: @R..: Additionally there's the fact that `pthread_t` need not be an integral type, and so if `pthread_create` returned a `pthread_t`, there wouldn't be an obvious way to check for an error condition.

Comment: @Managu: If I remember correctly, in the original spec it was required to be a scalar type, and only later relaxed to allow other implementations.

Comment: @Tudor for example creating child of thread1 :pthread_t thread3;int iret3;int *message3 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));iret3 = pthread_create( &thread3,???????, print_message_function, (void*) message3); what i have to write in place of ??.is it true?

Comment: @prjndhi: the second parameter represents the thread creation attributes. You can pass NULL for default attributes.

Comment: @prjndhi: Yes, I think so. You can post another question if you have other problems. :)